# Change user to root in between python program

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, subprocess

The executable program code is designed to make a power option in ubuntu like that in Windows. This will run for every user for 'init 0' or 'init 6' but for 'shutdown' and 'reboot' it needs the user to be root. I have tried using getpass and shlex to change to root but it is not working...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import getpass


a = 0
#b = 1
#c = 2
#d = 3
#e = 4

while a == 0:
    os.system("tput setaf 2")
    print '\n\n\t**************************************************************\n'
    os.system("tput sgr 0 1")
    print '\t\t\tWelcome to Nitin\'s PowerHouse\n'
    os.system("tput sgr 0 0")
    os.system("tput setaf 2")
    print '\t**************************************************************\n'
    os.system("tput setaf 7")
    print '\t\tEnter 1: for normal shutdown...\n'
    print '\t\tEnter 2: for normal reboot...\n'
    print '\t\tEnter 3: for fast shutdown...\n'
    print '\t\tEnter 4: for fast reboot...\n'
    print '\t\tEnter 5: for suspending...\n\n'

    os.system("tput setaf 3")
    a = int (raw_input ('\t\tEnter the option for power buttons: '))
    if a == 1:
        print "This script was called by: "+getpass.getuser()
        print "Now do something as 'root'..."
        subprocess.call(shlex.split('sudo id -nu'))
        os.system('shutdown')
        break 
    elif a == 2:
        os.system('reboot')
        break
    elif a == 3:
        os.system('init 0')
        break
    elif a == 4:
        os.system('init 6')
        break
    elif a == 5:
        print "This script was called by: "+getpass.getuser()
        print "Now do something as 'root'..."
        subprocess.call(shlex.split('sudo id -nu'))
        os.system('pm-suspend')
        #print "Now switch back to the calling user: "+getpass.getuser()
        #os.system('pm-suspend')
        break
    else: 
        os.system("tput setaf 1")       
        print '\n\t\tEnter a correct choice'

os.system("tput setaf 7")
raw_input('\n\t\tPress Enter to leave now...')
```

there is no error in the program but it doesn't work for option entered as 1 it requires:

```
    Must be root.
```

and for option 5 it says:

```
    Enter the option for power buttons: 5
    This script was called by: nitin
    Now do something as 'root'...
    [sudo] password for nitin: 
    root
    This utility may only be run by the root user.

    Press Enter to leave now...
```

Comment: Use `subprocess` not `os.system` and write the password to stdin or using communicate

Comment: You don't seem to be running 'shutdown' or 'reboot' with 'sudo' in the posted code. `subprocess.call(shlex.split('sudo id -nu'));  os.system('shutdown')` will be run in two separate shells, the first one just printing the results of the `id` command

Comment: To understand what is happening, run `subprocess.check_call(shlex.split('sudo id -nu'))`,  `subprocess.check_call('id -nu'.split())`—`sudo cmd` has no effect on following commands. If you need to run `pm-suspend` using `sudo` then run it using `sudo`: `subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'pm-suspend'])`.

Comment: @SimonFraser  You are right about the separate shells. I have entered into a newer shell just after this.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for your help. I got your method working for my program for suspending, rebooting and shut down too. I just wanted it to achieve using only python without altering the user permissions in ubuntu.